# lsd-slam installation failed during rosmake

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, opencv

I am trying to install the lsd-slam library without success. When typing during the last step of the installation: `rosmake lsd_slam`
I got this output:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['lsd_slam']                                                                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/marcel/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20150525-155638                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['lsd_slam'] to:
['lsd_slam_core', 'lsd_slam_viewer']                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> cmake_modules [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-10] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> geneus [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-11] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
 No Makefile in package rosclean                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common                                                                                                             
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< cmake_modules ROS_NOBUILD in package cmake_modules
 No Makefile in package cmake_modules                                                                                                    
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-9] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-9] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
 No Makefile in package rosmaster                                                                                                                
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-10] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-11] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
 No Makefile in package rosparam                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< geneus ROS_NOBUILD in package geneus
 No Makefile in package geneus                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-11] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-9] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-11] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation                                                                                    
[rosmake-11] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-9] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits                                                                                                    
[rosmake-9] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                                                                                                               
[rosmake-11] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> roslz4 [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-9] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization                                                                               
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< roslz4 ROS_NOBUILD in package roslz4
 No Makefile in package roslz4                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> rosbag_storage [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime                                                                                              
[rosmake-11] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< rosbag_storage ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag_storage
 No Makefile in package rosbag_storage                                                                                                 
[rosmake-11] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs                                                                                                                        [ 2 Active 24/43 Complete ]
 No Makefile in package std_msgs                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-11] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs                                                                                                    
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs                                                                                                    
[rosmake-11] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole                                                                                                            
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                                                                                                          
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
 No Makefile in package cv_bridge                                                                                                                
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch                                                                                                                
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
 No Makefile in package rostest                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
 No Makefile in package topic_tools                                                                                                          
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
 No Makefile in package rosbag                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
 No Makefile in package rosmsg                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
 No Makefile in package rosservice                                                                                                             
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
 No Makefile in package dynamic_reconfigure                                                                                  
[rosmake-8] Starting >>> lsd_slam_viewer [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesd_slam_viewer: 3.6 sec ]                                                                                                                                         [ 1 Active 41/43 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  CMakeFiles/videoStitch.dir/build.make:118: recipe for target '../bin/videoStitch' failed
  make[3]: *** [../bin/videoStitch] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/marcel/rosbuild_ws/package_dir/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_viewer/build'
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:851: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/videoStitch.dir/all' failed
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/videoStitch.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/viewer
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.9
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/build.make:355: recipe for target '../bin/viewer' failed
  make[3]: *** [../bin/viewer] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/marcel/rosbuild_ws/package_dir/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_viewer/build'
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:886: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/all' failed
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/marcel/rosbuild_ws/package_dir/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_viewer/build'
  Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/marcel/rosbuild_ws/package_dir/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_viewer/build'
  /opt/ros/jade/share/mk/cmake.mk:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package lsd_slam_viewer written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/marcel/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20150525-155638/lsd_slam_viewer/build_output.log                                        
[rosmake-8] Finished <<< lsd_slam_viewer [FAIL] [ 3.68 seconds ]                                                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package lsd_slam_viewer. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                                                   
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Built 42 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                                                              
[ rosmake ] /home/marcel/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20150525-155638
```

I followed the instructions of their [readme](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam/). I am using Ubuntu 15.04 with OpenCV 2.4.11 and ROS (Robot Operating System) Jade. I have to use OpenCV 2.4.11 or higher because my cameras are only supporting this or a higher version. So, there is not option to downgrade.

Also the messages ..."cannot find"... are confusing. These files exist but apparently cannot be found.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the help of a workaround. Possibly there is an error related to the path of some files which are starting with a `:/`. I guess that's related to some relict's of the Windows version.
After trying `rosmake lsd_slam` you can edit the CMakeCache.txt-file to remove these colons by using: `cat CMakeCache.txt | sed s/":\/"/"\/"/g > CMakeCache.txt2` and than replace the original file by using: `mv CMakeCache.txt2 CMakeCache.txt`.
That you have to do for each, the lsd_slam_core and lsd_slam_viewer.